# My code is only looping till a certain point and ignoring after that Python, Dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Data

```
slot : acu:1/1                         plannedtype : ngfcf                       actualtype : ngfcf                           operstatus : enabled              
errorstatus : noerror                                                                       availability : available            
alarmprofile : none                                                                          capabprofile : not_applicable       

slot : acu:1/2                         plannedtype : ngfcf                       actualtype : ngfcf                           operstatus : enabled              
errorstatus : noerror                                                                       availability : available            
alarmprofile : none                                                                          capabprofile : not_applicable   

slot : acu:1/3                       plannedtype : ngfcf                       actualtype : ngfcf                           operstatus : enabled              
errorstatus : noerror                                                                       availability : available            
alarmprofile : none                                                                          capabprofile : not_applicable
```

> As we can see the slot and other items are repeated, my loop is only inserting the first items in csv file i want to iterate through the repeated lines and add those values after":" to the next row of my csv file.

```
#reading a text file

import re
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

result = defaultdict(list)

with open('gthamelslot.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.findall(r"\s+(\S+)\s+:\s+(\S+)", line)
        for k,v in match:
            if k in ["slot",
                     "errorstatus",
                     "alarmprofile",
                     "manufacturer",
                     "mnemonic",
                     "pbacode",
                     "fpbacode",
                     "fpbaics",
                     "cleicode",
                     "serialno",
                     "failedtest",
                     "ltrestarttime",
                     "plannedtype",
                     "ltrestartcause"]:
                result[k].append(v)

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
writetocsv = df.to_csv("test.csv")
print(df)
```

> Output i got

```
slot     plannedtype  actualtype  errorstatus
acu:1/1  ngfcf         ngfcf        noerror
```

> output required

```
slot     plannedtype  actualtype  errorstatus
acu:1/1  ngfcf         ngfcf        noerror
acu:1/2  ngfcf         ngfcf        noerror
acu:1/3  ngfcf         ngfcf        noerror
```

Comment: Your code can't produce the output with shown input because e. g. "slot" would have to be preceded by at least one whitespace, "planned-type" has no hyphen in in-/output and more. Please edit your question carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following changes:

Change regex to  r"\b(\S+)\s+:\s+(\S+)" to allow match at beginning of line (change to look for word boundaries)

Some items such as "planned-type" in comparison list have '-' when that is not what you have in file (so remove '-' in fields you want such as plannedtype, actualtype,  errorstatus).

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

result = defaultdict(list)

with open('gthamelslot.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.findall(r"\b(\S+)\s+:\s+(\S+)", line)
        for k,v in match:
            if k in ["slot",
              "actualtype",
              "errorstatus",
              "alarm-profile",
              "manufacturer",
              "mnemonic",
              "pbacode",
              "fpbacode",
              "fpbaics",
              "cleicode",
              "serialno",
              "failedtest",
              "ltrestarttime",
              "plannedtype",
              "ltrestartcause"]:
                result[k].append(v)

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
writetocsv = df.to_csv("test.csv")
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
slot plannedtype actualtype errorstatus
0  acu:1/1       ngfcf      ngfcf     noerror
1  acu:1/2       ngfcf      ngfcf     noerror
2  acu:1/3       ngfcf      ngfcf     noerror
```

Comment: Still i only got a single line as an output. The same output which i got previously.

Comment: @AlterEgo--Here's a link to a shared online repl for my code: https://repl.it/@DarrylGurganiou/TallValuableInstances where it works.

Comment: @AlterEgo--was the repll code in the above link of use?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that:

- the source for the DataFrame should be a **list of dictionaries** (*rows*
  in the code below),
- the content of the current row is collected in a dictionary (*row*
  in the code below),
- each *slot* match starts a new row, so if *slot* has been matched and *row*
  is not empty, then start from appendding *row* to *rows* and make *row*
  an empty dict again,
- after the loop, the content of the last row should also be appended to *rows*.

So, taking the above into account, change your code to:

```
rows = []
row = {}
with open('gthamelslot.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.findall(r"(\S+)\s+:\s+(\S+)", line)
        for k, v in match:
            if k in ['slot', 'plannedtype', 'actualtype', 'errorstatus']:
                if k == 'slot':   # This match starts a new row
                    if bool(row): # Something gathered so far
                        rows.append(row)
                        row = {}
                row[k] = v
    if bool(row): # Something gathered so far
        rows.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

Note that:

- I deleted initial *\s+* from your pattern. Otherwise it failed
  to match *slot* starting just from the beginning of a line (without spaces
  before).
- In `if k in [...]` I left only column names included in your expected
  result. If you want more output columns, extend the list as you wish.